# Using `dynamic` keyword in C# doesn't compile

Tags: c#, dynamic, mono, ironpython

I'm trying to compile a piece of C# code that contains the `dynamic` keyword.
(I need this keyword for using ironpython.)
However, it doesn't compile, complaining that

```
error CS1980: Dynamic keyword requires 
`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' to be defined.
Are you missing System.Core.dll assembly reference?
```

The compiler I'm using is `Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1`.
I don't have `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute` in the list of possible references.

How can I make mono accept the `dynamic` keyword?

Comment: Do you have Mono's System.Core.dll referenced?

Comment: Did you add references to System.Core.dll, Microsoft.Dynamic.dll and Microsoft.CSharp.dll?

Comment: @TimothyP don't have either of them in my list.

Comment: You need to enable the C# 4 profile, sounds like you didn't.  Google "__enable_profile4=yes"

Comment: Thanks, I started working on an existing project that appeared configured to work with C# 2.0. -_-

Comment: You shouldn't NEED the dynamic keyword in your C# code.

Comment: @cbuteau Please read the question before commenting. It's about working together with IronPython. The `dynamic` keyword is simply *needed* for that.

Comment: I was chasing the misinformation that you needed dynamic keyword in using the IronPython engine.  You can instantiate the engine and expose typed objects to it.  I haven't used the dynamic keyword in its context yet.  You may need it to get objects back from the python.  But it doesn't HAVE to be used that way.

Comment: The latter is exactly my use case. I need to retrieve python objects from a python library into the C# part.

Comment: So that use case you do need the keyword and .NET 4.0+.   No bad blood was intended bro.   Is this case closed?  You should followup with a minipost and close it yourself.  I just learned a lot about embedded IronPython and was browsing the not closed list.

Comment: Yeah, IronPython is an interesting technology. By the way, you are right that I should've marked this question as answered. Will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comment of Hans Passant solved the problem:

> You need to enable the C# 4 profile, sounds like you didn't. Google
>   "__enable_profile4=yes"